# How to find the inverse of a boolean function?

Tags: digital-logic

There is a practice exercise before my exam in mid april that says: find the inverse of the boolean function: F = AB + BCD + AD. What does this mean and how do I do it?

The answer is F = A' * C' + B' * D' + A' * B' + A' * D' but how?

Comment: I think they meant a complement, not inverse, which has a different meaning in mathematics. Like \$\overline{F}\$

Comment: Draw the truth table for both. Note how they are related.

Comment: BTW, I have noticed that you have posted 4 questions here on the site and received formal answers to all of these except this one. Yet none of these was accepted by you. Such a behavior is not encouraged on SE network and considered to be "help vampirism".

Comment: Thank you, I now see that everywhere there is a 1 in the function, there is a 0 in the inverse function. I didn't know about the accept thing, sorry about that. I will take a minute now to look it up and accept all of the answers